# A property of the partitions of 311 with regard to the divisors of its parts

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a multiset of positive integers, its P-graph is the loopless graph whose vertex set consists of those integers, any two of which are joined by an edge if they have a common divisor greater than 1, that is, they are not relatively prime.

It can readily be verified that none of the partitions of 311 has as its P-graph the cycle on four vertices shown below.

[image]

Is it true that, for any of the 11 different graphs on four vertices, there is a partition of any number greater than 311 into four parts whose P-graph is precisely that graph.
In other words, is 311 the largest number whose partitions into four parts fail to "fall" *at least once* into each of the graphs of order 4?

[The graphs of order 4 can be viewed here](http://www.graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html#nodes4), for anyone wanting to ponder this question.

Comment: Have you checked this in some cases?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: Freddy Barrera has verified the assertion up to 400.

Comment: This is probably resolvable with a little bit of effort. For example, given an integer $N$, to have a partition with the square P-graph above, it suffices for there to be a solution in positive integers to $14 a + 15 b + 10 c + 21 d + N$ satisfying the coprimality conditions $(a,b) = (a,15) = (b,14) = (c,d) = (c,21) = (d,10) = 1$ (and I guess $14a,15b,10c,21d$ pairwise unequal). Counting such solutions for large $N$ is standard (use the Möbius function to detect coprimality, switch order of sums) and the argument is amenable to being done with explicit constants, verifying it for large $N$.

Comment: Freddy Barrera has now verified that beyond 311, and up to 1000, every number has a partition into four parts whose P-graph is the above square.